# Repeated characters in string

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function to identify whether or not a character is repeated in a given string.

```
int checkrow(char* row) {
    int count, r;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(row); i++) {
        count = 1;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < strlen(row); j++) {
            if(row[i] == row[j]) {
                count = count + 1;
            }
        }
        if(count > 1 ) {
            r = 0;
        }
        else {
            r = 1;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

This is my function at the moment, I am not getting an error or warning messages, but it is not identifying repeated characters.

I am very new to C and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It'll set `r = 1` then on the next loop it'll set `r = 0` again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each character you test, you set `r` to whether that character is repeated. So if the first character is repeated you set `r = 0`, but then if the second character is not repeated, you set `r = 1`.

You don't need to test every character. As soon you find a repeated character, you can return `0`. If you get to the end of the loop, nothing was repeated, so you return `1`.

```
int checkrow(char* row) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(row); i++) {
        for(size_t j = i + 1; j < strlen(row); j++) {
            if(row[i] == row[j]) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Congrats on beating me to this exact answer by a matter of seconds. One suggestion: `int len = strlen(row);` and then use this in the loop tests as the length of `row` isn't changing. Of course, `size_t` would also be more appropriate than `int` as well, but odds are the string isn't that big.

Comment: I believe most compilers will optimize out the repeted `strlen()` calls, so it's not necessary

Comment: @Chris Just checked godbolt.org, I was right.

Comment: Neat! I hadn't tested this yet, but was thinking it _might_ work if `row` were specified as `const char *`. I love it when I'm wrong and it means things are better than I thought.

Comment: @Chris The argument to `strlen()` is declared `const char *`. And the compiler can see that nothing in the function modifies the array.

Comment: The original code looks like it intended to return 1 with no dups and 0 when dups are found, so the return values above may need to be swapped.. (Possibly a validity check on a string that should have no repeated characters, returning 1 for valid.)